# How to set a ldflag for a library in home folder

Tags: compiling, gentoo, sabayon

I followed the following manual http://photivo.org/photivo/download_and_setup/linux how to compile Photivo on Sabayon:

graphicsmagick 16 bit

```
    wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick/1.3.18/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
    tar xfvz GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
    ./configure --prefix=/home/mictadlo/apps/ --with-quantum-depth=16 --enable-shared --without-lcms
    make 
    make install
```

Photivo

```
    sudo equo install mercurial
    hg clone https://code.google.com/p/photivo
    qmake PREFIX=~/apps/ CONFIG+=WithGimp
    make 
    make install
```

Error:

```
    $ photivo
    Photivo version 2013-03-17 (rev 57519a52a791)
    Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file "infinality/conf.d"
    Fatal error: Wrong GraphicsMagick quantum depth!
    Found quantum depth 8. Photivo needs at least 16.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why don't use emerge instead? graphicsmagick is in the repo IIRC

Comment: I thought it might break Sabayon, does it? Mean while I did it in the following way https://forum.sabayon.org/viewtopic.php?p=160682#p160682

Comment: Try some other overlays

Comment: LDFLAGS= -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/path_to_lib/, -lsomelib

Comment: Don't tag you question with distro tags if you don't plan to use their means; that said, manual compilation is more likely to break stuff than using your distro properly. /etc/portage/package.env is your friend...